# Web Design Practices? Mostly HTML or PHP?

Tags: php, html

I had just learned web development a while ago and made a a very novice site to practice. It looks terrible, but it's something to show I tried. I had extremely poor structure, didn't follow any standards, was using templates in Adobe Dreamweaver, etc. I had stopped working on it because of the vast amount of things that needed to be accounted for when making a website and starting learning some programming.

Now I'm trying to get back into it and do everything properly. I added a forum to the site and took a look at some of the source files to try to get a feel for how the pros do it. EVERYTHING was php. All the html was generated in PHP and the forum looked great.

What I want to know is how professional web-developers structure their sites. Mainly HTML with some php includes and things here and there, or mainly or even completely PHP? I understand that the forum is reading from databases and is most efficient when using PHP, but does this apply to most websites too? When I go to Facebook or Google or some web-developers custom-made blog, is that mostly PHP?

I know this can be considered quite subjective to the taste of the developer, but I have no clue where the middle ground lies here.

If it's at all possible, I would love to see some of the source files of the developers reading this.

Also, what programs are used? Just a text editor with syntax highlighting? Are the pages tested by uploading them or, do people have PHP servers installed to test the includes and things?

Comment: PHP is only one of many, many, many options.

Answer (score 4):

> When I go to Facebook or Google or some web-developers custom-made
>   blog, is that mostly PHP?

First of all, there are numerous development languages and methodologies, and you owe it to yourself to examine at least a few.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_development

This list doesn't account for the fact that companies (like Google) heavily extend existing technologies or roll their own (e.g. Google and Yahoo design their own hardware from scratch, at least in some cases).

> Also, what programs are used? Just a text editor with syntax
>   highlighting?

You can write code in any text editor, but projects quickly benefit from file organization, autocomplete, visual designers (sometimes), code refactoring tools, test coverage tools, etc. etc.

> What I want to know is how professional web-developers structure their
>   sites. Mainly HTML with some php includes and things here and there,
>   or mainly or even completely PHP?

This question is independent of PHP. In brief, logic should be separated from presentation and shared functionality should be reused. The [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern is very popular for achieving this.

Speaking of mainstream sites, it's my opinion (based on a few facts) that MySpace lost a great deal of market share due to **not** having a properly abstracted architecture that supported rapid deployment of new features and high performance.

> I have no idea where to go from here. I knew there were a lot of
>   options and structures, but I was hoping for an example or some
>   starting point.

There is no one "correct" starting point, but if you like PHP and you are starting to recognize some of the right/wrong ways to do things, you are headed in the right direction. Look for a [better editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_editors) if needed. Read a few articles on basic design patterns and best practices; they are all over the web.

If you want to branch out a little, download the free version of Visual Studio 2010 and try a .NET MVC web project. You can literally install, create a new project, and click the "Play" button to run.

Comment: Good answer.  Much more to the point than mine.

Comment: I have no idea where to go from here. I knew there were a lot of options and structures, but I was hoping for an example or some starting point.

Comment: @TimMedora, Do you have any personal recommendations though? I've heard of netbeans a lot. Also, about Visual Studio, I have it, but I'm currently using free webhosting and it doesn't allow ASP.net

Comment: @Walkerneo - Personally, I'm a Microsoft specialist and if I could only recommend ONE development platform, it would be .NET using Visual Studio, C#, ASP.NET, and MS SQL Server (the free Express edition can do a lot). My Java development experiences have mostly been negative. My experience with PHP is limited but I see many people being very successful with it (usually as part of the LAMP stack - Linux/Apache/MySQL/PHP).

Comment: BTW, if you want help on specific code that you are working on, you can post to: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are there any free webhosts you know of for ASP.net?

Comment: Not personally...but it looks like there are some: https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=free+webhosts+for+asp.net

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is how to separate content from logic, which is the tip of the iceberg of the larger question of scope when it comes to web page/web app development.  One problem with coming up with a "best practice" or generally-approved model is that what might be the best design might not actually work in every browser or work on a mobile device, etc.  But one thing to research is the idea of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic, which aims to separate the aspects of a site/page into various scopes or layers.

I'm not an expert on the topic, but the general idea is to have a Data Layer (from the db), a Logic Layer (your php/web server logic), and a presentation layer (your html).  To prevent too much overlap between the logic and presentation layer, many designers adopt an html template system, like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net), so that you can have your static HTML page marked up with the dynamic parts (user name, data table values, etc), and the PHP assigns those values to the template variables to be filled in.

Another aspect of this topic is the separation of your presentation layer itself. This generally breaks down into : Document layer (the actual HTML body), Presentation Layer (the look of the document, handled by CSS), and the Interactive layer (anything that should happen while the user is viewing the page, handled by javascript). These get pretty tangled into each other as well, but keeping them as cleanly separated as possible greatly helps your initial issue, as it helps prevent writing PHP that writes HTML that handles all three aspects.  Instead, your PHP might only write the document, and the CSS and JS handles everything else once it loads.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to know is how professional web-developers <s>structure</s> *pick the technologies* for their sites.

Companies use whatever they like, there is no such thing as best language for the web. They pick the technologies that suit their problem set and resources. There is not only PHP, there is [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/), [JavaServer Faces](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/) for example, and [a lot more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks).

With HTML5 and Javascript libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) or [Dojo Toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/) for example, you can build awesome dynamic websites. I think that is somewhere to start learning, and also use an editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). Note that with a text editor you force yourself to look at the code so you practice it and understand it; I would not prefer the Dreamweaver way. Also, you can challange yourself to make your sites [valid](http://validator.w3.org/) against W3C, and by doing so you will increase the quality of your site and code.

As you get more comfortable, you can proceed with PHP and/or the framework based on your preferred language, like [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) for PHP, which is great for learning [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). It is a long journey to become an experienced web developer, so take your time. You will have your own best practises and preferences, and with time you will find out how you can do better.

> If it's at all possible, I would love to see some of the source files
>   of the developers reading this.

As for coding styles, you can seek through existing [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=coding%20style%20guide), I think there are some for every language.